# Swift: Instagram Stories And Feed Cells Style

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement the Letgo or Instagram-like style feed with the categories/stories bar which I have done. but when I scroll through the posts it scrolls just within the cell and not as a whole view. So the stories bar just stays there until I reach the end of the collection view then the stories bar scrolls but goes back down because the cells act like there is not enough cells.

This is what i have so implement the cells.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDatasourse

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categoryCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell
    default:
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        return 110
    default:
        return tableView.frame.height - 110
    }
}
```

I have the categories bar's height to be 110 and the rest of the frame to be for the feed. Everything is in a regular view controller. If there's a better way to approach this where I can also tap on the bar to interact with the feed I'm open to reprogramming everything.

Structure :
ViewController

-TableView

—CategoriesCell (height 110)

—-CollectionView (hor)

—PostsCell (how to make this dynamic depending on the CollectionView content)

—-CollectionView (ver)

Comment: If you want Instagram style, why not use [IGListKit](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit)?

Comment: @Paulw11 no, I got the two separate types loaded and everything that’s not the problem. The problem is that when it all loads and the posts load up and I want to scroll through the post it only scrolls through inside the cell so if I make the cell height 200 or 2000 it’s the same thing it doesn’t scroll as a whole. Like when you scroll the story bar is still there. And when I scroll the story bar up you can see the ending of the posts cell. It’s not one unison scrolling , it’s two separate scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Its not scrolling because there are only 2 cells, table view can scroll if there are more cells which is not the case in this.

You will need to change the approach as you won't be able to add cell in cell which you have to do this in this. Eg, for 0th index cell which is for category you will have to add cells to show the data as in insta.

For categories/stories bar : Use collection view for this as table view doesn't have horizontal scroll by default and collection view can be more customized.

For feed : You can use either collection view or table view for this. The number of cells will be the number of feed to be shown so the table view will scroll until there is feed data.

Comment: If I increase the height of the second cell (the one that has the collectionview of the posts) then I can scroll but I want the height of the second cell to be dynamic so I don’t have to scroll the UICollectionView view but just as one long table view with one small cell and one dynamically set height cell.

Comment: You can set the height of second cell dynamically by  using **height for row at index ** delegate of table view. Calculate the height as number of row in collection view * height of each cell of collection view.
I am not sure if this will work and is a wrong approach to use. 

Use this structure :-
View controller 
|
> Collection view on top for stories
|
> Table view below it for posts

Comment: I had that way before, but the bar will just stay there. I want the whole view to scroll as a whole. no just what's within the cell.

Comment: Add a view in table view, just above the custom cell. This view will scroll up with 1st cell. You can use this view to add Stories Bar
Check this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/gvik8v